# UIScrollView for infinite slideshow

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am having a set of images.How can i use them to set an infinite slide show.The images should continue as a loop.I want to use only horizontal scroll in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

[Infinite Paging View](https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView)

i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this using this

```
 self.scrollviewImageList.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.imgTab.frame.size.width*no_of_images),self.imgTab.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: What is imgTab object.How can i define it?

Comment: Also what is scrollviewimagelist object?? can you give an example.

Comment: scrollviewImageList is your scrollview and imgTab is your image view.